# If I'm controlling an opponent's turn, do I get to chose where their commander goes?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-commander

While I'm controlling my opponent's turn, and, say, their commander dies in combat... do I get to choose whether or not their commander goes to the command zone? I'm assuming 'yes', as it is at the choice of its owner, and I'm currently making decisions for the owner.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, you do get to choose.

> 714.5. While controlling another player, a player makes all choices and decisions the controlled player is allowed to make or is told to make by the rules or by any objects. This includes choices and decisions about what to play, and choices and decisions called for by spells and abilities.

Where the commander goes is a choice they're allowed to make by the rules. There's no special exception or anything here, so yup, you can let their commander go to their graveyard if it dies in combat.

Comment: Or you can let it get exiled! BWAHAHAHA

Comment: @Samthere wait.... if you let their Commander get exiled, will they be unable to cast it again?

Comment: @Malco Yes, just as they can't cast it again if you let it get put into their graveyard (as in the question/answer) or shuffled into their library. Exile is a bit harder to come back from, though, sure.